# How to activate dynamite?

Tags: serious-sam-3-bfe

[image]

Look at this dynamite stick. Tauntingly blinking red (not pictured). Placed on this appropriately cracked wall. Annoyingly not impressed by my attempts to activate it. Not even hitting it with the sledgehammer gets it going.

How can I activate pre-placed dynamite?

Comment: I don't think the dynamite is pre-placed, it just looks like it but is actually just a marker that you can place dynamite there. It surprised me too at first but then I placed some dynamite there myself and detonated it as normal using the right mouse button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're going through that level, you'll come to a wall with visibly loose bricks (if you get to the cut-scene, you've missed it, it's to the left of that). Use a sledgehammer to break through the wall. Climb the building on the right all the way to the roof, jump across to the building on the left. It's difficult, might take a few tries. Inside the top floor is a hidden dynamite bundle.

Use that to blow the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you back up a few steps from your position in the screenshot, you can climb up on the pallets, sprint along the awning and jump over the wall.

The secret item within should provide you with an escape route ;) .